# How to reconnect to a VC if the bot gets disconnected?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

```
client.on("ready", () => {
    console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}`)
    const voiceChannel = client.channels.cache.get(channel_id)
    voiceChannel.join().then(connection => {
        console.log("Joined voice channel")
        function play(connection) {
            const stream = ytdl(video_urls[Math.floor(Math.random() * video_urls.length)], { filter: "audioonly" })
            const dispatcher = connection.play(stream)
            dispatcher.on("finish", () => {
                play(connection)
            })
        }

        play(connection)
    })
})
```

This is a basic code for music bot. How can it be made to reconnect to the voice channel if it's disconnected by someone?
I've seen one code which does it like this

```
setInterval(async function() {
  if(!client.voice.connections.get(SERVER)) {
    let channel = client.channels.cache.get(CHANNEL) || await client.channels.fetch(CHANNEL)
    if(!channel) return;

    const connection = await channel.join()
    connection.play(ytdl(LIVE))
  }
}, 20000)
```

How can it be implemented in mine?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `setInterval()`, you could use events. They are plenty more efficient.

For example you can use this:

```js
const connection = client.voice.connections.get(SERVER)
connection.on("disconnect", () => {
  let channel = client.channels.cache.get(CHANNEL) || await client.channels.fetch(CHANNEL)
  const dispatcher = channel.join()
  dispatcher.play(ytdl(LIVE))
})
```

If you have any other questions, don't hesitate to comment!

Happy coding! :)

Comment: How can this disconnect be implemented in my code? I couldn't figure out.

Comment: Hi! When you connect to the channel, say, `const connection = channel.join()`, then you would put the `connection.on("disconnect")`.